# Apparent Infinite Loop while trying to update Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe in which there is a field called `section`. Some rows have the value "Concurrent Opinion - x", where x is an index relative to the current document, which is another field in the dataframe. I need to set the value of the `section` field to "Concurrent Opinion - x" for all the rows in the same document that are below (after) of "Concurrent Opinion - x" and before "Concurrent Opinion - x+1".

I can get the rows matching "Concurrent Opinion" for the whole dataframe, but I can't seem to set the rows in between to the desired values: when I try to set the value of section for the matching rows, the code doesn't stop, yet, somehow, it doesn't hang. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my code

```py
    concurrent_opinions_ids=paragraphs_df[paragraphs_df['section'].str.contains("Concurrent Opinion")].index
    for index in concurrent_opinions_ids:
        #get document_pos for paragraph
        curr_pos=paragraphs_df.loc[index, 'document_pos'].copy()
        curr_doc=paragraphs_df.loc[index, 'document'].copy()
        curr_section=paragraphs_df.loc[index, 'section']

        paragraphs_indices=paragraphs_df[(paragraphs_df['document']==curr_doc) & (paragraphs_df['document_pos']>curr_pos)].index
        for ind in paragraphs_indices:
            #set section to current section
            paragraphs_df.loc[ind, 'section']=curr_section
```

The last line, `paragraphs_df.loc[ind, 'section']=curr_section` is the one giving me trouble.

I also tried `curr_section=paragraphs_df.loc[index, 'section'].copy()` to get the value, thinking the issue might be cause for some sort of reference issue, but it gave me an error saying that *'str' object has no attribute 'copy'*

The dataframe before the change:

```py
        id  document  paragraph_id  previous  next  length  document_pos  \
4001  4001        16           187       186   188      35         55282   
4002  4002        16           188       187   189       4         55317   
4003  4003        16           189       188   190      86         55321   
4004  4004        16           190       189   191     230         55407   
4005  4005        16           191       190   192    1702         55637   
4006  4006        16           192       191   193     154         57339   
4007  4007        16           193       192   194      49         57493   
4008  4008        16           194       193   195     720         57542   
4009  4009        16           195       194   196       4         58262   
4010  4010        16           196       195   197     232         58266   
4011  4011        16           197       196   198     297         58498   
4012  4012        16           198       197   199      36         58795   
4013  4013        16           199       198   200     206         58831   
4014  4014        16           200       199   201      42         59037   

                     section function  \
4001                Decision  Pending   
4002                Decision  Pending   
4003  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4004                Decision  Pending   
4005                Decision  Pending   
4006                Decision  Pending   
4007                Decision  Pending   
4008                Decision  Pending   
4009                Decision  Pending   
4010                Decision  Pending   
4011                Decision  Pending   
4012                Decision  Pending   
4013                Decision  Pending   
4014                Decision  Pending   

                                                   text  
4001                  NILSON PINILLA PINILLA Magistrado  
4002                                                 25  
4003   SALVAMENTO DE VOTO DEL MAGISTRADO JORGE IVÁN ...  
4004   PRINCIPIO DE OFICIOSIDAD Y DE PREVALENCIA DEL...  
4005   Considero, sin embargo, que la argumentación ...  
4006   FACULTAD OFICIOSA DEL JUEZ ADMINISTRATIVO-Jue...  
4007    DERECHO PROCESAL-Finalidad (Salvamento de voto)  
4008   La finalidad principal del derecho procesal y...  
4009                                                 27  
4010   DERECHO DE ACCESO A LA ADMINISTRACION DE JUST...  
4011   CONSTITUCIONALIZACION DEL DERECHO PROCESAL- O...  
4012                 Referencia: expediente T-3.407.509  
4013   Acción de tutela instaurada por Tito Edmundo ...  
4014           Magistrado Ponente: ALEXEI JULIO ESTRADA
```

This is how the dataframe should look like after the change:

```py
        id  document  paragraph_id  previous  next  length  document_pos  \
4001  4001        16           187       186   188      35         55282   
4002  4002        16           188       187   189       4         55317   
4003  4003        16           189       188   190      86         55321   
4004  4004        16           190       189   191     230         55407   
4005  4005        16           191       190   192    1702         55637   
4006  4006        16           192       191   193     154         57339   
4007  4007        16           193       192   194      49         57493   
4008  4008        16           194       193   195     720         57542   
4009  4009        16           195       194   196       4         58262   
4010  4010        16           196       195   197     232         58266   
4011  4011        16           197       196   198     297         58498   
4012  4012        16           198       197   199      36         58795   
4013  4013        16           199       198   200     206         58831   
4014  4014        16           200       199   201      42         59037   

                     section function  \
4001                Decision  Pending   
4002                Decision  Pending   
4003  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4004  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4005  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4006  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4007  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4008  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4009  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4010  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4011  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4012  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4013  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   
4014  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Pending   

                                                   text  
4001                  NILSON PINILLA PINILLA Magistrado  
4002                                                 25  
4003   SALVAMENTO DE VOTO DEL MAGISTRADO JORGE IVÁN ...  
4004   PRINCIPIO DE OFICIOSIDAD Y DE PREVALENCIA DEL...  
4005   Considero, sin embargo, que la argumentación ...  
4006   FACULTAD OFICIOSA DEL JUEZ ADMINISTRATIVO-Jue...  
4007    DERECHO PROCESAL-Finalidad (Salvamento de voto)  
4008   La finalidad principal del derecho procesal y...  
4009                                                 27  
4010   DERECHO DE ACCESO A LA ADMINISTRACION DE JUST...  
4011   CONSTITUCIONALIZACION DEL DERECHO PROCESAL- O...  
4012                 Referencia: expediente T-3.407.509  
4013   Acción de tutela instaurada por Tito Edmundo ...  
4014           Magistrado Ponente: ALEXEI JULIO ESTRADA
```

Comment: @PaulH `section` is a text field with type `object`. I suspect I might have accidentally entered into a recursion by not passing a value but a reference. Yet, I tried using `copy()` on the section field and it didn't work. I know the cycle runs properly because I'm able to print the indices. What is giving me trouble is setting the section field for the matching rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First a note

You say: *I also tried `curr_section=paragraphs_df.loc[index, 'section'].copy()` to get the value, thinking the issue might be cause for some sort of reference issue, but it gave me an error saying that `'str' object has no attribute 'copy'`.*

You may `.copy()` variables representing a dataframe, a list, a tuple, but not a string itself. Check again e.g. pandas copy. More on the subject: stackoverflow.com/q/4794244/12846804

---

#### Answer

**Alternative input data I used, for a more representative MRE**

With more than one document and "Concurrent Opinion", to demonstrate processing documents separately.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'document' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'section'  : ['Decision','Concurrent Opinion - 1','Decision','Decision','Concurrent Opinion - 2','Decision','Decision','Decision','Concurrent Opinion - 1', 'Decision'],})

   document                 section
0         1                Decision
1         1  Concurrent Opinion - 1
2         1                Decision
3         1                Decision
4         1  Concurrent Opinion - 2
5         1                Decision
6         1                Decision
7         2                Decision
8         2  Concurrent Opinion - 1
9         2                Decision
```

---

**Processing**

1. Extract opinion number in a temporary column

```py
# Take the digit to a new column
df['opinion'] = df.section.str.extract('(\d)')

   document                 section opinion
0         1                Decision     NaN
1         1  Concurrent Opinion - 1       1
2         1                Decision     NaN
3         1                Decision     NaN
4         1  Concurrent Opinion - 2       2
5         1                Decision     NaN
6         1                Decision     NaN
7         2                Decision     NaN
8         2  Concurrent Opinion - 1       1
9         2                Decision     NaN
```

2. Reconstruct "section" for each separate document

```py
def fill_opinion(df_d):
    '''
    Fill "concurrent opinions" for one document
    '''   
    # You may replace "section2" with "section" to directly overwrite the section column. Here as a new column for demo.
    return df_d.assign(section2 = 'Concurrent Opinion - ' + df_d['opinion']).ffill()

df.groupby(by='document').apply(fill_opinion         # propagate concurrent opinions
                        ).fillna('Decision'          # fill rows prior to concurrent opinion in each document
                        ).reset_index(drop=True      # clean-up index
                        ).drop(columns = 'opinion')  # remove temporary column

   document                 section                section2
0         1                Decision                Decision
1         1  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Concurrent Opinion - 1
2         1                Decision  Concurrent Opinion - 1
3         1                Decision  Concurrent Opinion - 1
4         1  Concurrent Opinion - 2  Concurrent Opinion - 2
5         1                Decision  Concurrent Opinion - 2
6         1                Decision  Concurrent Opinion - 2
7         2                Decision                Decision
8         2  Concurrent Opinion - 1  Concurrent Opinion - 1
9         2                Decision  Concurrent Opinion - 1
```

Nick's answer looks much more efficient, provided 'decision' is the only value to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by replacing all `Decision` values with `NaN`, grouping by `document` and forward filling, and then replacing any remaining `NaN` values with `Decision` again (to fix up the values before the first `Concurrent Opinion`. For example with this sample data:

```
data = {
  'section': ['Decision', 'Decision', 'Concurrent Opinion - 1',
              'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 
              'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 
              'Concurrent Opinion - 2', 'Decision', 'Decision', 
              'Decision', 'Concurrent Opinion - 1', 'Decision',
              'Decision', 'Concurrent Opinion - 2', 'Decision', 
              'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 'Decision', 
              'Concurrent Opinion - 3', 'Decision', 'Decision', 
              'Decision'],
  'document' : [1] * 14 + [2] * 14 
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['section'] = (
    df['section']
        .replace({ 'Decision' : np.nan })
        .groupby(df['document'])
        .transform('ffill')
        .fillna('Decision')
    )
```

Output:

```
                   section  document
0                 Decision         1
1                 Decision         1
2   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
3   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
4   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
5   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
6   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
7   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
8   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
9   Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
10  Concurrent Opinion - 1         1
11  Concurrent Opinion - 2         1
12  Concurrent Opinion - 2         1
13  Concurrent Opinion - 2         1
14                Decision         2
15  Concurrent Opinion - 1         2
16  Concurrent Opinion - 1         2
17  Concurrent Opinion - 1         2
18  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
19  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
20  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
21  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
22  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
23  Concurrent Opinion - 2         2
24  Concurrent Opinion - 3         2
25  Concurrent Opinion - 3         2
26  Concurrent Opinion - 3         2
27  Concurrent Opinion - 3         2
```